# Validating correctness of $ref in json schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

The requirement is to validate given json schema that there are no dangling $ref pointing to the definitions within the file.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-6/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "date": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\-\\d{4}$"
    },
   },
   "properties": {
     "my_date": {"$ref": "#/definitions/dat"}
   }
}
```

Here, there is a typo in the reference (dat instead of date). I want to catch such instances rather than having a run time failure.

Library being used: https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator

Comment: Why do you not want to do a try catch and handle the error?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't throw any exception till runtime. I want to detect it if someone changes the schema and has a typo rather than it failing in production.

Comment: It sounds like you want to write some tests for your application. Tests which confirm the JSON Schema validates some specific test json as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate that the use of $ref resolves by digesting the JSON, recursivly extracting the value of $ref, splitting on slash, and checking the path exists.

This COULD get more complicated as you might have external references which target URLs.

I can't give you any code as I don't know JAVA. It doesn't seem like what you want is specifically available using that library.

Comment: That is the last resort. I was hoping that the library should provide something of that sort as it is a very common use-case.

Comment: @AbhayDubey It's actually not that common a use case. A JSON Schema has many ways you can write nonsense. It's up to the author of the schema to make sure they have written it as expected. Why would you expect the library to also lint your schema?

Comment: Yes, the author needs to make sure that the schema is written correctly but issues like typo can still be handled at the time of changing the schema rather than having issue in production. I do see your point and we can have custom code to handle it.